# Tools for generating PDF Report?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

This is a request for an appropriate tool. No code at this juncture.

I have a multi-page dashboard developed in JavaScript. The objects in the dashboard include D3 charts, plotly.js charts, and DataTable tables.

I want to find a library or set of tools that can generate a comprehensive PDF report from the dashboard.

In the dashboard, users can select up to 8 pages with unique items. The pages are rendered on demand. When the user clicks a button to download a PDF report, I want to have all of the objects written to the PDF, regardless of whether they have been rendered.

My thought is to write a serialized object to a "collection array" when a page is rendered (and then generate the PDF using the collection array as the source). But, how do I collect the objects for pages that are not rendered?

Does anyone have suggestions about a pdf library to use?

Any suggestions about how to produce objects that have not been rendered?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have a way of rendering these pages at the server side to any format, such as HTML, SVG or even as images? If yes, try the [free evaluation of LEADTOOLS SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads), which can convert almost any type of document or image to PDF, using very simple code. (Disclosure: I work for the SDK’s vendor). If you need help using the SDK, there's [free technical support](https://www.leadtools.com/support/supportoptions) for both SDK owners and free evaluation users alike, through email and online chat.